# Making a central div fill the rest of the available space

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a HTML5 and CSS project and am having a problem getting the containers to display properly.

What I want to have is a header bar at the top, a wrapper that contains 2 other divs and then a footer at the bottom which is always at the bottom of the window or at the bottom of the content whichever is further down.

Here's a snippet:

```css
html, body
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#wrapper
{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: purple;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

header
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}


#articleContainer
{
 background-color: blue;
 width: 75%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 80px;
}

#articleContent
{
 width: 70%;
 background-color: yellow;
 float: left;
}

#articleSideBar
{
 position: relative;
 width: 28%;
 background-color: green;
 float: right;
 margin-left: 2px;
 margin-right: 2px;
 display: inline;
 margin-top: 0px;
 float: right;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>index</title>
  <link href="ArticleStyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <header>
    Header
   </header>
   <div id="articleContainer">
    Article Container
    
    <div id="articleContent">
     The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs back. All good men must come to the aid of the party
    </div>
    
    <div id="articleSidebar">
     Article Sidebar
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

At the moment the articleContainer is only the height of however many lines there are. What I want to have is the formContainer to fill the rest of the screen, I've tried adding the height: 100%; attribute but then this feels the form container over the screen size. I.e. a vertical scrollbar appears which is about the same height as the header. How can I get the formContainer to fill the available screen space without the scroll bar. However, if the content is larger than the form container should expand to fill the extra space.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: add it to jsFiddle so that we can more easily visualize what you are planning on doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want a css3 solution the one you're looking for is setting `height: calc(100% - 80px);` on `#articleContainer` as demonstrated in **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CeGjY/)**, however this will not work in all browsers.

Example using [**old flexbox model**](http://jsfiddle.net/CeGjY/5/) css:

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#articleContainer {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}

#articleContent
{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#articleSideBar
{
    position: relative;
    width: 28%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
}​
```

same thing, but this time using [**new flexbox model**](http://jsfiddle.net/CeGjY/7/)
css

```
html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

#articleContainer {
    width: 75%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
}

#articleContent
{
    width: 70%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#articleSideBar
{
    position: relative;
    width: 28%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: auto;
}​
```

[**version with only the paragraph in yellow**](http://jsfiddle.net/CeGjY/8/)

Comment: Thanks, I went for the second solution, I did try the first one with the calc solution but this didn't make any difference for some reason. Was using google Chrome so thought it would have done.

Comment: Hmm, works for me with Chrome `Version 22.0.1229.94 (161065)` on Linux, if you add the footer take that into consideration as well, also you might want to set min-height instead of height.

Comment: I've just found that if the content in the left hand div is to big to fit, the div expands but the rest of it doesn't so everything overlaps

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that, looking into it.

Comment: @Boardy do you really want a css3 solution? I could suggest one with flexbox if you want. Alternatively javascript is your best guess to set the min-height property of your div.

Comment: ideally, a lot of my the different elements of the real template will make use of the new css3 styles

Comment: @Boardy updated example, only works in chrome cause I only added properties for chrome, you have to add other vendor prefixes for it to work in other browsers, to have compatibility with older browsers use http://flexiejs.com/ if you want just a smaller part with yellow background just add an element inside that and move the background-color rule to it

Comment: added new flexbox model example as well, I also wrote properties only for chrome, but same thing as before applies and you can just type in the yellow box to see it expand

Comment: thanks so much for your help, working perfectly in chrome, the older style with the flexbox the one with the calc doesn't which is strange as I am using the same chrome version you mentioned only difference is I am on windows. It doesn't work in jsfiddle either so I guess its a windows chrome thing. As you say the layout doesn't currently work in IE but hopefully I can figure out what to do to make it look the same. Thanks again for your help, much appreciated

Comment: @Boardy haven't you tried flexie from http://flexiejs.com/ for ie? They say it should work, also maybe they've updated it and it only works with new style flexbox, you also have that in my answer

Comment: no not yet, I'm just looking for the download link, its pretty well hidden

Comment: Bottom right of the page where it says `More info? View the source or download`, link goes to http://github.com/doctyper/flexie/archives/master which redirects to https://github.com/doctyper/flexie/downloads

Comment: Thanks for that was well hidden, I've included it, and jquery, and it makes the wrapper now use the full width of the screen which it wasn't before, but the height isn't filled to the bottom, and the yellow and green divs aren't side by side, and instead the green is underneath the yellow. From what I've seen looking at their source for the examples you just need to include the script

Comment: Try adding one more normal div inside it or something, maybe it will fix them, I really don't know how flexie works, and I don't have my own solution to this as I'm really not interested in supporting older IEs anymore. It should work in ie10 with -ms- prefix. You might need to add some other properties for it to work in ie :(

Comment: thought you may want to know managed to get it work in IE as well, I am using the calc css3 option you mentioned, it was working before I was looking at the wrong container, think I was getting tired. It also works in IE but not need the flex, not for IE9 anyway, not tested older versions yet. I've updated the jsfiddle  at http://jsfiddle.net/CeGjY/12/ if you wanted to take a look

Comment: @Boardy calc rulez, I really hope people will get rid of all their old IE versions, I'm really trying to encourage this, asking as many clients as possible if they're ok with their sites not working in old browsers (especially IE)

Comment: I know what you mean, hate building websites for IE at the best times as it always seems to behave differently to other browsers, older versions of IE are an absolute nightmare. Thanks again for your help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I've used this method before, the tricky part is getting the header and footer in the right location. Once you have that the rest should fall into place:

#### jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ug5JR/

#### css:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }

header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

article {
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-bottom: -100px;
}

article section {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

footer{
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

p:hover {
  height: 4000px;
}
```

#### markup:

```
<header></header>
<article>
  <section>
     <p>Hover me and I'll push the content larger than the page</p>
  </section>
</article>
<footer></footer>
```

The trick is to get the negative margins to absorb the space used by the header and footer, this causes the 100% calculation to correct itself. You can then use any internal element to counter the negative margins with padding or margin on top and bottom. So whilst your article element is pretty much 100% height of the page, your article > section element will appear the right height and lay it's children out correctly.